# Invalid Cross Reference Key, Record Type ID

Tags: record-type, user

> INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid
>   for the user: 012j00000010ALFAA2: [RecordTypeId]:

How do I fix the above error? I'm the system admin on this box and I have looked online could not find the solution to the problem

Answer (score 3):

I tried adding a comment but my reputation is < 50. So I will answer here instead.

Try this.

Go to:

> Setup > Administer > Manage Users > Profiles > System Admin > Object
>   Settings > [Object Name]  > Tick the appropriate "Assigned Record
>   Types"

I faced your problem before on Case and this is how I fixed my error and I believe the error should be similar to any other object names :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to

`Setup -> Manage Users -> Profiles`

Find the corresponding user's profile, edit, search for "Record Type Settings" and ensure that the record type is available for that profile and that object.

Comment: I'm the `System Admin` on the box I navigate to as you described above but I do not see `Record Types`

Comment: In the `General User Permissions` I see the `Manage record types and layouts for Files` unchecked other that I do not see Record Types any where.

Comment: Did you have a look at this answer? - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47881/invalid-cross-reference-key-record-type-id-value-isnt-valid-for-user-012v000